# Will you run in the 2023 moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderation

For the past few years I and Alvin Reyes have been the moderators for this great community, and due to the low traffic we haven't bothered with an election.

However, given the team is currently below the minimum of 3 moderators, we wonder if community members would be interested in running in a new moderator election?

**We will be scheduling the election to take place at some point in January or February 2023, and the site's long term success is somewhat tied to this election's success.** Please let us know if you'd be interested in running by answering below (note this is not an official nomination thread yet, just a pulse check).

Comment: Hi nuno, sure, ill run for it.